# Index was outside the bounds of the array while reading from a file

Tags: c#

I hope all of you are having a nice day. So I fixed one error of my program but there's another :/

So here's the code where I create my  and read the data from a file:

```
  void ReadData(string fileName, Branch[] branches)
    {
        string shopsName = null;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@fileName))
        {
            string line = null;
            line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line != null)
            {
                shopsName = line;
            }
            Branch tempBranches = TempBranch(branches, shopsName);
            string address = reader.ReadLine();
            string phoneNumber = reader.ReadLine();
            while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine()))
            {
                string[] values = line.Split(';');
                string facturer = values[0];
                string model = values[1];
                double capacity = double.Parse(values[2]);
                string energyClass = values[3];
                string assemblyType = values[4];
                string color = values[5];
                string attribute = values[6];
                double cost = double.Parse(values[7]);
                Fridges fridge = new Fridges(facturer, model, capacity, energyClass, assemblyType, color, attribute, cost);
                tempBranches.fridges.AddFridge(fridge);
            }
        }
```

And there's the code where I use the TempBranch method. The error is in this line: `if (branches[i].ShopsName == shopsName)`. Hopefully you can help me, cuz I was trying to fix this yesterday for 30 minutes and it still wasn't working :D

```
private static Branch TempBranch(Branch[] branches, string shopsName)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MaxNumberOfFridges; i++)
        {
            if (branches[i].ShopsName == shopsName)
            {
                return branches[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: In C# if a Variable implements the Interface `IEnumerable` you can do a `foreach` loop. Try this: `foreach(Branch b in branches) {if (b.ShopsName == shopsName) return b;}` and then outside the loop you can return null like you're doing right no

Comment: the issue is here `int i = 0; i < MaxNumberOfFridges; i++`, so instead change it to this `int i = 0; i < branches.Length; i++`

Answer (score 3):

If you replace `MaxNumberOfFridges` with `branches.Length` it will only try to find a `Branch` that's within the range of the `branches` array. The reason it's not working is because you're trying to access an index which is greater than the `Length` of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. Use foreach, if you dont know the lenght of array.

```
private static Branch TempBranch(Branch[] branches, string shopsName)
    {
        foreach(var branch in branches)
        {
            if (branch.ShopsName == shopsName)
            {
                return branch;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: *If you dont know the length of array*, what about `branches.Length`?

Comment: Yeah, sure you are right. Tbh foreach is much cleaner solution, prevents typo like <= vs >= etc. And syntax is much more simple.

Answer (score 0):

This  raised error because `MaxNumberOfFridges` is bigger than branches `length`.. to simplify it, assume `MaxNumberOfFridges` is `20` but `arry length` is 10, so you are trying to access element `11` in array which is outside of array length.

to fix it

```
  for (int i = 0; i < branches.Length; i++)
    {
        if (branches[i].ShopsName == shopsName)
        {
            return branches[i];
        }
    }
```

other option is to use foreach loop

```
foreach(var b in branches)
{
    if (b.ShopsName == shopsName)
    {
        return branches[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to make use of a LINQ query,

```
return branches.Where(b => b.ShopsName == shopsName).FirstOrDefault();
```

EDIT:

To NullReferenceError which occurs in your new post occurs due to null being returned in your function where your shop gets created. This due to not finding the given shopname.

So it tries to add an fridge to an shop which does not exist, which is not possible. You will have to add a check so that this does not occur.